# Extracting .mp3 files and names from an .m3u file

Tags: newline, line-endings

I'm working on a website that lists music for a user to chose from that based on data in a json file. The file contains information like the album name, artist, year it was released, the number of tracks etc. and, where I'm struggling, an .m3u file containing a playlist for all the songs on that album.

I'm not having a problem actually playing the .m3u file but my problem comes where I need to extract the .mp3 file names from the .m3u file and display them in a list on the website so the user can see the songs on the album before they play it or choose individual songs to listen to.

I have everything in place to display a list, even using the number of tracks data from the json file to make sure it's the right length, but I'm struggling with a way to extract this data.

Here's an example of one of the files;

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:9,Horrible Theme
mp3/01 - Horrible Theme.mp3

#EXTINF:114,My Freeze Ray
mp3/02 - My Freeze Ray.mp3

#EXTINF:35,Bad Horse Chorus
mp3/03 - Bad Horse Chorus.mp3
```

And so on all the way down to the final file

```
#EXTINF:132,Horrible Credits
mp3/14 - Horrible Credits.mp3
```

I'm not sure if this will be a problem, but there are also some .m3u files that I need to extract the .mp3 file names from that have all data on a single line. Like this;

```
#EXTM3U#EXTINF:9,Horrible Thememp3/01 - Horrible Theme.mp3#EXTINF:114,My Freeze Raymp3/02 - My Freeze Ray.mp3#EXTINF:35,Bad Horse Chorusmp3/03 - Bad Horse Chorus.mp3
```

I was wondering if anyone has dealt with something similar to this before and whether or not they could help explain how this might be done using jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While I think it's basically a good question, without any specific problems in your existing code it's way too broad to fit here. I suggest you show what you've tried and what doesn't work specifically.

Comment: what is source for this .m3u files, are you getting from any web service?

Comment: @venkat7668 The m3u file is from a server, the paths for the mp3 files are relative to the position of the m3u file on the server which is why they're not complete paths.

Answer (score 0):

You have [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters generated by one system and read/interpreted by another. E.g. the file was created on Mac and read on Windows or Linux or vice verse. Some advanced editors like [Editplus](https://www.editplus.com/) or [Kate](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kate/) allow you to convert line endings between different formats in a single operation. It's also possible to process the file with a program or script that detects different types of newline characters and parses accordingly.